# Failed to connect to mongodb in ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I followed this tutorial: http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb

Its strange, the first time I followed the tutorial everything worked.
But now, one day after I wanted to play with the code again I coudn't start
the server. This is what I get:

> alex@alex-System-Product-Name:~/blog2$ node app.js Express server
>   listening on port 3000 in development mode
>
> node.js:134
>           throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
>           ^ Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
>       at [object Object]. (/home/alex/blog2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:189:47)
>       at [object Object].emit (events.js:67:17)
>       at [object Object]. (/home/alex/blog2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:110:14)
>       at [object Object].emit (events.js:67:17)
>       at Socket. (/home/alex/blog2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:301:10)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)
>       at Array. (net.js:836:27)
>       at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26) alex@alex-System-Product-Name:~/blog2$

Any suggestions to fix this problem?

**EDIT:**

I just did:

```
alex@alex-System-Product-Name:~/blog2$ sudo service mongodb start
mongodb start/running, process 9847
alex@alex-System-Product-Name:~/blog2$ sudo service mongodb status
mongodb stop/waiting
alex@alex-System-Product-Name:~/blog2$
```

Not sure if it is running.

and this is what I get if I type `$ mongo` in the command line:

```
alex@alex-System-Product-Name:~/blog2$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.8.2
Tue Nov 15 08:09:50 *** warning: spider monkey build without utf8 support.  consider rebuilding with utf8 support
connecting to: test
Tue Nov 15 08:09:50 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:79
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Are you sure mongodb is running? It seems like node can't connect to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This fixed the problem:

http://www.synchrosinteractive.com/blog/1-software/47-mongodb-repair-on-ubuntu

Apparently mongodb creates a lock file when the database crashes or something.
Deleting that file and repairing mongodb fixes the problem:

> Manually remove the lockfile: sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
>
> Run the repair script: sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf
>   --repair

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that MongoDB is not running.

When running MongoDB unattended, you provide the `mongod` process with a `--logpath` parameter which points to a file. Check that file to see the reason `mongod` is failing.